# Where are GIS Chat Rooms?

Tags: support, status-completed, faq, chat

I've noticed that the chat rooms aren't too busy.

I wonder if part of this is that users cannot find them?

Answer (score 9):

Once you have a reputation of 20 or more you will have the [Talk In Chat privilege](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

To find the GIS Chat Rooms since the [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live):

1. From the Main (or Meta) site click on the Stack Exchange "burger" at top right and then next to **Geographic Information Systems** you will see **chat**.

[image]

[image]

2. Click on **[chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gis.stackexchange.com)** to see the GIS Chat Rooms with the main one being called **[GIS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis)** (use this link to go straight to it):

[image]

3. Click on a chat room to enter.

---

There's also a link to chat at the bottom left of the page, under "help".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Note: The description below applies to some GUI experimentation that
>   was happening in 2011.

---

There's also a link to chat waaaaay down at the bottom of the page, between "blog" and "data".

And you might occasionally see links in the right-hand sidebar while reading a question.

The one at the top comes and goes - it'll be there if there hasn't been a recent blog post (but when the blog is active, it'll be a link to that instead).