# Should Moderators Stop Pointing to the Chat Room on Questions?

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of moderators pointing users to the chat room (often without hint as to where to find the chat room).  And when users do manage to find it (or are actually given a link to it), they find it largely empty and/or under-utilized.  This would seem unhelpful, particularly when people come here asking questions in good faith that this community exists to help GIS users.

**Should Moderators Stop Pointing to the Chat Room on Questions?**

Comment: May you explain when such situations occur (in what circumstances/why moderators point users to the chat) and what alternative do you propose?

Comment: Here's a good example regarding Learning resources for Enterprise GIS with FOSS - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319048/learning-resources-for-enterpise-gis-with-foss

Comment: comments automatically get flagged when there are more than 10 as 'too chatty' this cleans up the question can moves it to the proper place. > https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119011/how-should-long-comment-threads-with-important-information-in-them-be-handled/ (it's part of stack exchange design)

Comment: Another example is the question around GIS Management I posed recently, which was closed, asking what typically comprises a GIS budget?

Comment: Then that is a flawed design when people effectively don't use chat.  Why point to something that people aren't using?  It's futile.

Comment: The example you provided was not written by a moderator. You can agree or disagree if that Q is too broad (hence, closed), but assume it is, pointing to chat is better than nothing (few people use it, but sometimes people try helping from there).

Comment: I look in on the GIS Chat Room at least once a day, and I suspect that I am not alone in that habit. If I see a discussion there that interests me then I'll usually join it. Unlike the Main site, discussion in  chat is fine and encouraged.

Comment: While it might be unfortunate that the chat room is under-utilized, the point of pointing to the chat room is because *that's the last place on SE* for discussion/off-topic/conversational-nature that doesn't belong to the main Q&A place in the first place... unless, of course, the alternative is to ask on other sites, other than SE (e.g. Quora, Reddit, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) is under-utilized.

As part of our strategy to try and address that we have a Meta Q&A on [Where are GIS Chat Rooms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/where-are-gis-chat-rooms)

The other part of our strategy is to try and point askers of Main site questions which are seeking discussions, ideas and/or opinions towards it.

Such questions do not fit the focused Q&A format of the Main site but the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) welcomes them.