# Product recommendation / map request on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, recommendations-questions

I'm looking for a beautifully drawn wall map of all of Europe (from Portugal until all the way where the Urals meet the Arctic Ocean, possibly including the islands in the Arctic Ocean associated with Europe), with an equal area projection (probably Lambert Azimuthal equal area).

Would asking recommendations for such a map (on paper or as a high-resolution image that can be printed on a plotter) be on-topic on GIS.SE?  Apart from the "beautifully drawn" bit, they're all objective criteria, but I'm not directly interested in processing the data; I just want it on my wall.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is covered on the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page of our Help Center where it says:

> **To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), avoid
>   asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

I think your question can be perceived as (with the bit I interpreted in bold):

> **What’s your favorite** wall map of all of Europe (from Portugal until
>   all the way where the Urals meet the Arctic Ocean, possibly including
>   the islands in the Arctic Ocean associated with Europe), with an equal
>   area projection (probably Lambert Azimuthal equal area)?

and would result in potentially multiple answers, with voting from various users as to which they think are the most beautifully drawn.  I think this would make the Q&A that results into a poll.

Such a question would be fine and encouraged to ask in the [GIS Chat Room](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/where-are-gis-chat-rooms).

As far as I know no questions of this form have ever been removed (deleted) from the Main site but many have been closed.